# Syncing Button Class and Dropdown

Tags: jquery, class, drop-down-menu, click, synchronization

I am having a problem with the way my button operates. If you click it, a class is added to the button and a dropdown appears. That part is fine. It's just, if somebody spams clicks, very fast, the button class and the dropdown can get out of sync - Where the button has no class but the dropdown has appeared, or the dropdown hasn't appeared and the button has a class.

The following is my HTML

```
             <ul>
                <li><a class="drop" tabindex="1"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The following is my CSS

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

The following is my jQuery

```
jQuery(".drop").click(function(event) {

        // Variables
        var theDrop = jQuery(this).next("ul.dropdown");
        theDropState = theDrop.is(':visible');
        // Slide Mechanism
        jQuery("ul.dropdown").stop().slideUp(200);
        if(!theDropState){
            theDrop.stop().animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, '600') 
        }
    });

    jQuery(".drop").click(function() {
        theClickState = jQuery(this).hasClass("open")
        jQuery(".drop").removeClass("open");
        if(theClickState){
                jQuery(this).removeClass("open") 
        }
        if(!theClickState){ 
            jQuery(this).addClass("open") 
        }
    });
```

Does anybody have a solution where the button class and the dropdown stay in sync?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't bind the click event twice to the button. put the code of the second block in the first. like that:

```
jQuery(".drop").click(function(event) {
    // Variables
    var theDrop = jQuery(this).next("ul.dropdown");
    theDropState = theDrop.is(':visible');
    // Slide Mechanism
    jQuery("ul.dropdown").stop().slideUp(200);
    if(!theDropState){
        theDrop.stop().animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, '600') 
    }
    //the second block
    theClickState = jQuery(this).hasClass("open")
    jQuery(".drop").removeClass("open");
    if(theClickState){
            jQuery(this).removeClass("open") 
    }
    if(!theClickState){ 
        jQuery(this).addClass("open") 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It worked a lot better with this method, but I was still able to break it by clicking fast enough (although it was harder.)

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to fix it, by a reuse of the variables to tie in the events.

I did

```
    if(theClickState){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("open") 
    }

    else if(!theDropState){ 
        jQuery(this).addClass("open") 
    }
```

Instead of

```
    if(theClickState){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("open") 
    }
    if(!theClickState){ 
        jQuery(this).addClass("open") 
    }
```

Seems a bit of a weird script, but it works, so i'm happy!